# Is there a way to start a debugging session to an installed app in windows phone?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone

I am just beginning to program in Windows Phone so sorry for the noob question.

I would like to know if there is a way to start a debugging session to an already installed application, say downloaded from the store. Browsing through the developer center I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh781607.aspx#BKMK_The_easy_way_to_start_debugging) link. A section called "Start an installed app in the debugger" indicates that in my Visual Studio DEBUG menu, there should be a "Debug Installed App Package" option. However, I am not seeing it there.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible, you can't debug an application installed from the store because it's a xap / appx, you don't have the decompiled code. You can only debug your Windows Phone projects.